# Dolby home theater error message

Tags: audio, drivers

Every time I start up my computer, I get this error message:

> The current Dolby audio driver is 7.2.8000.17 and the software
>   application expects driver version 7.2.700.7. Please install a valid
>   driver and software application combination.

This appeared after using IOBit's Driver Booster program. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling my Realtek Audio Driver in the device manager on Windows - didn't fix it. I have also tried to rollback to previous version, yet it is not highlighted and will not let me rollback. I am using a custom computer with Logitech speakers and these specs (from the Speccy program):

```
Audio 
Sound Cards 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
Intel Display Audio 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
Corsair USB Headset 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
Webcam C260 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA High Definition Audio 
Playback Devices 
Realtek Digital Output(Optical) (Realtek High Definition Audio) 
Speakers (Corsair CA-HS1 USB Headset) 
BenQ V2200Eco-0 (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) 
Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio) 
Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)    (default) 
Recording Devices 
Microphone (Corsair CA-HS1 USB Headset) 
Microphone (Webcam C260)    (default) 
Speaker Configuration 
Speaker type    Stereo
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DriverMax-  http://www.filehorse.com/download-drivermax/

Its just like Driver Booster. Try to update your Audio Driver.

Or in other case, download the version 7.2.700.7 itself. I think its gonna solve the problem.